# Phantomjs - render text as images on Ubuntu Server

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, phantomjs, converters

I use phantomjs and html to pdf node package. On local env (MacOS) everything is ok. When I use the same app on Ubuntu Server (16.04), phantomjs generates PDF with images instead of text (on image per page).

I was looking for info and found that it can be caused by external resources - yes, I used additional custom font in my styles. But after changing to local (file:/// and base in render options) problem still occurs. Don't sure why it's platform-depended issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: install fonts locally on server (on /usr/share/fonts and /usr/local/share/fonts/). After that, Phantom can use them without any issues.